Is there a tutorial on learning how to use formating on Stackexchange Maths?
I would like to post a question but need to express a number of symbols that are not on my keypad. I have a Chromebook.
I thought there may be a question on stackexchange or some resource I can use to learn to use symbols so I can create my equation and make it look presentable to Stackexchange. I know I have the wrong tag. Sorry but don't know where to post the question, what tag to use or if the question is appropriate for Stackexchange Maths.

Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation would be a good place to start. Most of the $LaTeX$ commands work, but not all.

Probably best asked on meta.

@Red Five Awesome that is what I was looking for and the basic tutorial quick reference. I didn't know where to look. Thank you.
